# How to clear the screen with \x1b[2j?

Tags: c

How do we implement `clrscr()`? Googling it I found that `\x1b[2j` can be used to clear the screen but how do we use it?

Comment: it depends on your OS and environment in general.

Comment: I wonder if this question makes sense at all. Either you create a "fullscreen" app, then you will already know (platform- etc. dependent) how to position the cursor, and much more, including how to clear the screen. Or you create a cmd line utility, which looks okay if you just use line breaks and maybe backspaces or CRs (for line counts redrawing on the same place for example)...

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The standard C library doesn't provide a way of clearing the screen. You need an operating-system-dependent library for that.

Under DOS and Windows, for a program running in a DOS or Windows console, you can use the DOS/Windows extensions provided in the core C library shipped with the OS:

```
#include <conio.h>
clrscr();
```

Under unix systems, you can use the curses library, which is provided with the OS. Ports of the curses library exist for most operating systems, including Windows, so this is the way to go in a portable program. Link your program with `-lcurses` and use

```
#include <curses.h>
erase();
```

Some terminals and terminal emulators perform special functions such as clearing the screen when they receive an escape sequence. Most terminals follow the ANSI standard which defines a number of escape sequences; `"\x1b[2J"` is such a sequence, and its effect is to clear the screen. Note the capital `J`. On such a terminal, `fputs("\x1b[2J", stdout)` clears the screen. This is in fact what the curses library does when you call `erase()` on such a terminal; the curses library includes a database of terminal types and what escape sequences to use on the various types.

Answer (score 3):

If you're confident that is the control sequence you need to use, then:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    fputs("\x1b[2j", stdout);
    return(0);
}
```

This deliberately omits the newline - but you might be better off with adding one after the 'j'.  However, as [Gilles](https://stackoverflow.com/users/387076/gilles) points out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646333), there are other ways to do it which have merits compared with this solution.

Comment: @fahad: what platform are you on? If you're on plain legacy DOS, you need to have ANSI.SYS loaded for terminal escapes to work. Not sure about Windows. On Unix it should always work unless you have a *really* odd terminal with nonstandard escape codes.

Comment: @fahad: OK - in that case, go with Giles suggestion and the `clrscr()` function.

Comment: actually i want to implement clrscr(). dont need  a header file :(

Comment: "\x1b[H\x1b[2J" works on OSX. On windows' cmd there is no such a sequence AFAIK.

Comment: @Tvaroh: In the old days of DOS it was common for systems to have a driver called ANSI.SYS, or any of a number of aftermarket alternatives, installed.  The key-redefinition functions of ANSI.SYS were dangerous (many aftermarket versions omitted them), but having configurable support for those sequences would have been nice.  I wonder why MS left them out entirely in later command-line drivers?

Answer (score 2):

This is a so called ANSI Escape Sequence that controls text terminal and will work with any ANSI compatible Terminal [1]:

- `\x1b[2J` clear screen and send cursor to home position.
- `\x1b[H` send cursor to cursor home position.

Just `printf("\x1B[2J");` or `echo "\x1B[2J"` it or whatever print method suits you :-) I use that with `printf()` for initial terminal clear screen when producing a debug output logs from an embedded system over uart connection, but you can use it as well on a standard Unix-like terminal with `echo`  :-)

[1] https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code

Answer (score 0):

On Windows you may try

```
#include <tchar.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>

void clrscr(void)
{
 HANDLE std_out = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
 CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO cbi;
 COORD origin = {0,0};
 int buf_length;

 GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(std_out,&cbi);
 buf_length = cbi.dwSize.X*cbi.dwSize.Y;
 FillConsoleOutputCharacter(std_out,0x20,buf_length,origin,0);
 FillConsoleOutputAttribute(std_out,0x07,buf_length,origin,0);
}

int _tmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[], wchar_t *envp[])
{
 DWORD i;
 _tprintf(TEXT("Clear screen probe...\n"));
 clrscr();

 return 0;
}
```

"\x1b[H\x1b[2J" works on OSX.

Answer (score 0):

```c
#include <unistd.h>    
write(STDOUT_FILENO, "\x1b[2J", 4);
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please edit your answer to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).