# Clear the screen and buffer

Tags: c, linux

I have this sample program. It clears the screen and the scrollback buffer.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int
main(void)
{
  printf("\ec");
  return 0;
}
```

However I have read that

> not all terminals take the ANSI/VT100+ escape sequences.

So I am wanting to use something like `erase();` as
[Gilles suggests](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3646333). However `erase` and friends seem to only clear the screen and not the buffer.

Comment: Clearing the scollback buffer is a bit user-hostile, isn't it? Why should your app clear something it might not have written?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you using Windows you can use this

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
  system("cls"); //call to system function to clear screen.
  return 0;
}
```

[This thread](http://osdir.com/ml/gnu.screen.user/2006-01/msg00029.html) has the following suggestion:

In the window whose scrollback you want to delete, set the scrollback to zero, then return it to its normal value (in your case, 15000).

If you want, you can bind this to a key:

```
bind / eval "scrollback 0" "scrollback 15000"
```

You can issue the `scrollback 0` command from the session as well, after typing `C-a :`. HTH.

Answer (score 1):

C has no concept of a screen or scrollback buffer, so this can't be solved using C alone. Your system may provide ways to achieve the desired effect, in essence rendering your program no longer a C program, but a program written for "*The C implementation as found on Frobozz Magic V1.42 using the Frobniz compiler and linked with the CleanScreen Library toolkit*". Save yourself from the nightmare of nonportable programming and forget the idea. Try to solve *useful* problems like implementing an algorithm in C and forget useless chrome like screen clearing. (If you really must, link with a termcap library and call the appropriate function).